# Swift 5 PopGesture İssue

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, swift5

I have problem with interactivePopGestureRecognizer. In my app when I'm in my first view controller when I do left swipe gesture (There isn't any previous screen) my app freezes. When I look in debug panel there look like second view controller is showing but in reel device its frozen in first view controller. İf I do left swipe gesture than my app comes normal again.

I have been try that solution but didn't work for me =>

Also I insert  UINavigationViewController,UITabbarNavigationViewController to my BaseViewController

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {


    if (navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1)
    {
         self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
         self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
        navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

in panel screen's look same like in this photo.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdQDl.png)

Comment: It may be worth making your question more specific, so others users can help.